# Firebase analytics showing unidentified release version and screen name. How is it possible

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have an android app which is using Firebase as the backend. The app is in production and looking at the firebase analytics report, I found that the Latest Release Version contains some unidentified version number. When I checked the engagement screen names, I found all the screens used in this latest release version doesn't belong to my app.

So the question is:

- How is it possible for some other unidentified app to send events to my Firebase account.
- How to find which app is sending those events.
- Is some malicious app posing as my app? If yes, then how to block such access.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

> How is it possible for some other unidentified app to send events to my Firebase account.

All Firebase products expose APIs that can be invoked by anyone with an internet connection.  The SDK isn't required.

> How to find which app is sending those events.

That's probably not going to be possible for you.  If you suspect abusive behavior, you can report that to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

> Is some malicious app posing as my app?

It's not possible to know for sure, but it is possible that something is invoking the APIs directly, or there is some app out there that's not configured properly.

> If yes, then how to block such access.

You can't block it, but as I said, you can report it to Firebase support.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I will check with Firebase Support and will update if I get something conclusive.